# Replacing text on the document body in PHP

Tags: php, string, templates, import, replace

How can I replace the text on the active document body on a PHP file on code execution?

Do I have to import a file, replace text on it and then echo it or can I just manipulate the document I run the PHP script on?

I am trying to use templates for easier HTML editing like :usernamecomeshere: and then replacing that :usernamecomeshere: with the actual value. I am wondering If I can do it on one file only instead of loading a file and then displaying it.

Comment: You can always use the PHP DOM for manipulating the file contents if you're looking for a more permanent fix; or use some form of database like SQL or XML (or even a TXT file) to hold the body content and call it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll want to look up str_replace() on google. You can search an entire string and replace specified keywords simply.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm getting your question correctly, you don't need to important a file and echo the document. You can directly manipulate the document itself. For example, in the below sample, you can directly echo the contents of `$username` in a way that's interspersed with HTML code.

**index.php**

```
 <?php
     // handle code to login
     $username = "David";
 ?>
 <html>
     <body>
         <p>Hello, your username is <?php echo $username ?></p>
     </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Worth pointing out is that PHP itself is a templating engine. If you want to replace text, you can do it using PHP such as:

```
<?php
$user = 'Ugur';
?>
<html><head></head>
<body>
<h1>Hello <?php echo $user; ?></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Beyond this sort of simple usage, you may want to look at various template engines, which allow you to do much more elegant things, but are more complex. Take a look at [mustache](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php), perhaps?

If you're trying to make these modifications after the page has loaded, remember that PHP runs on the server-side, not the user-side. For that, you need Javascript.